# Linking a datetime graph with numerical graph in bokeh

Tags: python, csv, datetime, bokeh

I am trying to create a `gridplot` using `bokeh`.

I am trying to col3 vs col4 in plot1 and col3 vs col1 (`datetime` when col3 was measured) on plot2.

plot1 is portraying nicely, but plot2 is entirely empty. I am using Python3.

```
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from bokeh.models import DatetimeTickFormatter, NumeralTickFormatter
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
output_notebook()

plot1 = figure(width = 600, height = 600, x_axis_label = 'Col3', y_axis_label = 'Col4')
plot1.dot(data['Col3'], data['Col4'], size = 8, alpha= 0.5)

plot2 = figure(x_range=plot1.x_range, width = 600, height = 600, y_axis_type = 'datetime', x_axis_label = 'Col3', y_axis_label = 'Col1')
plot2.dot(data['Col3'], data_francis['Col1'], size = 8, alpha= 0.5)
plot2.yaxis[0].formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter(months = '%m/%Y')

joint_plot= gridplot([[plot1, plot2]])

show(joint_plot2)
```

data

```
Col1          Col2          Col3         Col4  
2023/01/09  00:00:00        89.8        867.40      
2023/01/09  00:01:00        89.8        867.04      
2023/01/09  00:02:00        89.7        867.14    
2023/01/09  00:03:00        89.8        867.06     
2023/01/09  00:04:00        89.8        867.15     
...            ...       ...         ...             
2023/07/27  09:32:00        14.8        122.86      
2023/07/27  09:33:00        14.8        122.55     
2023/07/27  09:34:00        14.8        121.55     
2023/07/27  09:35:00        14.8        122.78    
2023/07/27  09:36:00        14.8        121.66
```

The dataset is roughly 250 000 entries large. Not sure if that makes a difference.

Would appreciate any input!
Thanks!

Comment: What is the actual type of `Col1`? Is it a real datetime type, or are those just ISO date strings? If the latter, they need to be converted to actual datetime values. Bokeh uses string values for categorical factors, which is definitely not what you'd want here. As an aside you should explicitly create one `ColumnDataSource` that both plots share, especially with these data sizes. The code above will send two copies of all of `Col3`.